# Sandboxing to allow multiple processes open the same port

Tags: linux, bash, networking, parallel-processing, virtualization

---

## Background

I have a command-line application that I use to connect to a remote device on port `1234`. I cannot change the port number, and I do not have access to the source to rebuild this tool. I'm currently working in a lab where all ports except SSH are blocked. To get around this, I create a tunnel, i.e.:

```
ssh -L 1234:remotehost:1234 sshuser@remotehost
```

Now, I can just point my CLI program at `localhost:1234` to connect with my CLI tool to the desired host.

---

## Problem

This CLI tool needs to run for about an hour straight, and I have about 200 remote hosts to test with it. I would like to parallelize this task. Unfortunately, I can only create a single tunnel on my local machine using port `1234`.

---

## Question

Is there a (trivial/simple/automated) way to jail/sandbox my CLI tool so that I can launch 100 instances in parallel (i.e. via a shell script) so that each instance "thinks" it's talking to port `1234`? For example, does Docker or KVM provide some sort of anonymous/on-demand compute node feature that I could setup rapidly? I'd rather not have to resort to manually deploying and managing a slew of VirtulBox hosts via [vagrant](/questions/tagged/vagrant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can use multiple IP addresses locally.  Each local IP address on the client will allow you to create another tunnel.  Currently, you are using localhost.  But your client also has an IP address.  You can prove my point by trying this syntax:

```
ssh -f -N -L 127.0.0.1:1234:remotehost1:1234 sshuser@remotehost1     # this is default 
ssh -f -N -L <local-IP1>:1234:remotehost2:1234 sshuser@remotehost2  # specifying non-default value <local-IP1>
```

Now, you just need to figure out how to give your client multiple IP addresses (secondary addresses).  Then you can expand this beyond 2 parallel sessions.

I've also added -f and -N to your ssh syntax to put ssh into the background (-f) and to not issue any commands.

Using -R tunnels in the past, I've found that I need to enable GatewayPorts on the server (/etc/ssh/sshd_config).  In the  case of -L , I don't see the need.  However, the ssh man-page explicitly mentioned GatewayPorts associated with the -L function.  You may need to play around a bit.  I just tried this out on my Mac and I was able to get it going without any GatewayPorts considerations.

Comment: Beautifully simple. Can't believe I overlooked this. Thanks!